# pygame sprite not moving

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

I'm faced with a logic error where the sprite simply doesn't move regardless of input.
My code will be below so no context is left out, it's fairly short.
Is there a better way of moving the sprite apart from the blit?
I've seen somewhere stuff about updating the sprite or some such, done quite differently to simply blitting it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import random
import math

screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,400])
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
player_x=350
player_y=200
player_x_vel=0
player_y_vel=0
rot_player=pygame.image

pi=math.pi

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        global player
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.pos=(350,200)
        self.image=pygame.image.load("arrowtest.png").convert()
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        screen=pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area=screen.get_rect()
        self.speed=10
        self.state="still"
        self.reinit()       

    def reinit(self):
        self.state="still"
        self.movepos=[0,0]

    def update(self):
        newpos=self.rect.move(self.movepos)
        if self.area.contains(newpos):
            self.rect=newpos
        pygame.event.pump()

    def moveup(self):
        self.movepos[1]-=(self.speed)
        self.state="moveup"
    def movedown(self):
        self.movepos[1]+=(self.speed)
        self.state="movedown"
    def moveleft(self):
        self.movepos[0]-=(self.speed)
        self.state="moveleft"
    def moveright(self):
        self.movepos[0]+=(self.speed)
        self.state="moveright"
    def moveupright(self):
        self.movepos[1]-=(self.speed)
        self.movepos[0]+=(self.speed)
    def moveupleft(self):
        self.movepos[1]-=(self.speed)
        self.movepos[0]-=(self.speed)
    def movedownright(self):
        self.movepos[1]+=(self.speed)
        self.movepos[0]+=(self.speed)
    def movedownleft(self):
        self.movepos[1]+=(self.speed)
        self.movepos[0]-=(self.speed)

    def angleplayer(self):
        mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dx=mouse_pos[0]-player_x
        dy=mouse_pos[1]-player_y
        rads=math.atan2(-dy, dx)
        rads %= 2*pi
        angle = math.degrees(rads)
        print angle
        rot_player.image=pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, angle-90)

done=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while done==False:

    player = Player()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            fired_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            fired=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.angleplayer()
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.moveup()
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.movedown()
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.moveleft()
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.moveright()

            print "co ords", player_x,player_y
            print "x vel", player_x_vel
            print "y vel", player_y_vel

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player.movepos=[0,0]
            player.state="still"
            player.angleplayer()

        screen.fill(white)
        screen.blit(player.image, player.pos)

    clock.tick(20)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you are creating *a new player* every iteration of your main loop:

```
...
while done == False:
    player = Player()
    ...
```

You want to create the player *once*, so move the creation outside the loop:

```
...
player = Player()
while not done:
    ...
```

---

Second: To get the position of the player, you use `player.pos`:

```
...
screen.blit(player.image, player.pos)
...
```

but you never update `player.pos` (it's always `(350,200)`), you only change `self.rect`:

```
def update(self):
    newpos=self.rect.move(self.movepos)
    if self.area.contains(newpos):
        self.rect=newpos
    pygame.event.pump()
```

either use `player.rect` to get the player position, or update `player.pos` accordingly:

```
def update(self):
    newpos=self.rect.move(self.movepos)
    if self.area.contains(newpos):
        self.rect = newpos
        self.pos = self.rect.topleft
        # don't call pygame.event.pump() here. Doesn't make any sense :-)
```

---

Third, you update the player position in the `update` function, but you never call it. Call it before drawing the player:

```
...
while not done:
    ...
    player.update()
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.pos)
...
```

---

You can simplify your code alot by setting `movepos` directly and removing the `move...` functions.

working example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
colors = pygame.color.THECOLORS
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700,400])

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(colors['green'])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(350, 200)
        self.speed = 4

    def update(self):
        dx, dy = self.movepos[0] * self.speed, self.movepos[1] * self.speed
        self.rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)


done=False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player()

while not done:

    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT):
        break

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    l, r, u, d = [pressed[k] for k in pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s]
    player.movepos = -l + r, -u + d
    player.update()

    screen.fill(colors['white'])
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Also note that you fill the screen and draw the player once for every event that occurs. That will lead to the effect that your program will not run smoothly. Just call the draw functions once every loop.

Comment: That helped heaps, thank you. To be honest I didn't even know what the pump did, I was just following a tutorial. I'm not sure whether it's worth starting a new question to ask, but how would I go about making the movement smooth? Right now it only moves once each time I press the keys.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. The key is to use `pygame.key.get_pressed` to check if a key is pressed rather than to check for a `KEYDOWN`-event.

Comment: BTW, which tutorial are you following? There are a lot of crap tutorials lurking out there :-)

Comment: Alex: Check out this serieshttp://eli.thegreenplace.net/category/programming/python/pygame-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of move functions. Try combining them into a simple two function class like this example:

```
class Puck(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, speed, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
```

The two main controllers are the self.rect.left and self.rect.top. By changing their values, you can move the sprites like in this example.

```
#Name of varible# = Puck('#Image File#', [#value of self.rect.left#, value of self.rect.top]
```

Then you can use events to change them like:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit(0)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_UP:
            random.rect.top =random.rect.top - 75
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            random.rect.left = random.rect.left - 75
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            random.rect.top = random.rect.top + 75
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            randoml.rect.left = randoml.rect.left + 75
        elif event.key == K_w:
            random.rect.top = random.rect.top - 50
        elif event.key == K_a:
            random.rect.left = random.rect.left - 50
        elif event.key == K_s:
            random.rect.top = random.rect.top + 50
        elif event.key == K_d:
            random.rect.left = random.rect.left + 50
```

This should be able to move your sprite.