# pygame: mysterious lack of sprite movement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

For some reason, my `Player` sprite is not moving when I press the arrow keys.
It was moving before, but now it does not move at all, and I don't see any problems
with the code I'm using (plus, no exceptions are raised). Here is the relevant code 
(tell me if I need to add more):

```
def move(self,up,down,right,left): #move function in Player class
    if up and self.rect.y>0: 
        print'up'
        self.rect.y-=self.speed
    if down and self.rect.y<650:
        print'down'
        self.rect.y+=self.speed
    if right and self.rect.x<650:
        print'right'
        self.rect.x+=self.speed
    if left and self.rect.x>0:
        print'left'
        self.rect.x-=self.speed

...

#in while loop, under "for event in pygame.event.get():"
elif event.type == 2: #pygame.KEYDOWN
    if event.key in range(273,277): #if the key is an arrow key
        if event.key==273: #up
            up=True
        elif event.key==274: #down
            down=True
        elif event.key==275: #left
            right=True
        else:               #right
            left=True
```

Neither of the following answer my question:
[This,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367930/pygame-python-sprite-not-moving-what-have-i-done-wrong-no-errors)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809309/pygame-sprite-not-moving)

I am on Windows 10, python 2.7.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run, otherwise we can't tell you precisely what you're doing wrong and how to fix this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your block of code inside the for loop nested in the while loop.
Is the while loop infinite, or rather, does it stop when you don't want it to?
Also, are you calling the `move` function directly after the if statement, and after you do so, are you *resetting* the variables for the directions?
Like this:

```
#in while loop, under "for event in pygame.event.get():"
elif event.type == 2: #pygame.KEYDOWN
    if event.key in range(273,277): #if the key is an arrow key
        if event.key==273: #up
            up=True
        elif event.key==274: #down
            down=True
        elif event.key==275: #left
            right=True
        else:               #right
            left=True
    move(up,down,left,right)
    up,down,right,left=False,False,False,False
```

Hopefully, this helps you track down your mistakes.

Comment: But upon clicking on a key again, the sprite should still move because at least one of those variables is still `True` before the reassignment

Comment: Anyways, the reassignment should only happen in `event.type = pygame.KEYUP`

Comment: the `while loop` is terminated when I click the red X in the corner of the window. I reset the variables' direction with a `pygame.KEYUP` event, and the `move` function is part of `Player().update(up,down,right,left...)` right before my drawing code.

Comment: You can perhaps condense your code, making no need for my last line of code. Instead, you could do
`up=(event.key==273)
down=(event.key==274)
etc.`

Comment: @9.0 Why do you have a function in a function? You should split them and call `Player().move(up, down, right, left)` or combine them

Comment: actually @AnthonyPham I think it is standard `pygame.sprite.Sprite` protocol to call all of a sprite's functions with a single call of `sprite_group.update()`, that updates all the sprites in `sprite_group`. [Look at this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html). Click on `pygame.sprite.Sprite` then `pygame.sprite.Sprite.update`.